# Detect clicks on button array with a single method

Tags: arrays, methods, jbutton, actionlistener

Im working in a school project, a minesweeper. Will be 20x20, so it has 400 buttons. Its there a way to add an actionEvent/actionPerformed and implement a generalized method for the whole array? Or there is an easier way?

Comment: Treat the whole array as a big single button that can be clicked at any place. If you have click coordinates, you can transform them into particular cell index of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that (using jQuery for convenience but you can do it with Vanilla JS too):

Your HTML:

```
<div id="buttonsHolder">
    <button data-num=1>1</button>
    <button data-num=2>2</button>
    <button data-num=3>3</button>
    ...
    <button data-num=4>4</button>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript:

```
$('#buttonsHolder').on('click', 'button', (function(evt){
    var buttonNum = $(this).attr('data-num');
    // Now, buttonNum variable holds the button number has clicked.
});
```

Of course instead of use `data-num` atribute you can use whatever data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the buttons inside a container (i suppose). Add a actionhandler to that to capture a click. And read the 'target' variable of the event, and see if that is a button